# How to shutdown and close this particular connection?

Tags: python, sockets, connection, shutdown

How do I shutdown and close this particular connection?

```
import socket
import socks
from urllib.request import urlopen

socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "localhost", 9150)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
urlopen("http://www.sourceforge.net/")
```

I've tried `socket.socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)` but that doesnt work at all:

```py
TypeError: descriptor 'shutdown' requires a '_socket.socket' object but received a 'int'
```

Comment: Just close it. Close implies shutdown unless the socket is shared with a child or parent process.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You mean like this? 

```
socket.socket.close()
```

Comment: Sadly, that doesnt work either. What am I missing?

Comment: `socket.socket = socks.socksocket` I have no idea what you are trying to do here but what you are doing is wrong. You have rebound the attribute `socket` in the socket module to some rando thing and in the process have hidden the socket class from your code.